# Persist the selected value of static dropdownlist in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
@Html.DropDownList("CType",new List<SelectListItem> {  
new SelectListItem{Text = "All",Value = "0"},
new SelectListItem{Text = "Outgoing",Value ="Outgoing"},
new SelectListItem{Text = "Incoming", Value  ="Incoming"},
}, new { @class = "form-control input-md"})
```

If I'm selecting the second value, I want to persist that selected value of dropdown across multiple requests

Comment: in view @StephenMuecke

Comment: If its in the view, it will be lost as soon as you redirect. You need to persist it on the server if you want to be able to get it for other requests.